# Turn off excel merge cell warning from matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to merge cells in excel from Matlab and I keep getting a merge cell warning "It will only keep the..." and the person has to press ok to accept.  How can I turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access to the Application object? Try:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```